# Visual Studio 2012 forgets SDL configuration when i start a new project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2012, sdl

I followed instructions from this site: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php

and all works fine, but when i start new project(C++->Win32->Empty Project), all configurations is forgetted and i must to set configuration again.
What i need to do?

For configuration i go Project->Properties and then follow instructions from upper site.

I hope that you understand me.

Comment: You can make a template project

Comment: @MahmoudFayez Ok, i export template, and how i can to import that template in my project? Just Open Project or something more?

Answer (score 2):

Use property sheets.  On the main menu, go to "View->Other Windows->Property Manager".  You should see a tree view, the root of which is your project.  That should expand to a list of all your configurations, by default that would be "Debug" and "Release".  If you expand those, you should see a list of property sheets that are being applied to each configuration.  You should see one named "Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user" that is being applied to both "Debug" and "Release".  You can edit that one, and your settings will be loaded on every new project you create.  Or you can create a new property sheet with all your custom settings, then load it in to be used by projects at your discretion.

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e.aspx